# Parse BLE advertising packets in C/C++

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, node-modules, bluez, beacon, nrf52

I'm working on Nordic's nrf52840 BLE chip, which is scanning the nearby available beacons.
I'm getting BDADDR, Name and RSSI value using my application which is in C(Used Bluez's api).

Now i want to write a C/C++ application which could parse the beacon advertising packets and get the sensor data from the packets.

I have observed that Noble module of Nodejs can do the job easily, but i don't have a knowledge of node.

So is there any library/APIs available using which parsing of BLE sensor advertising packets is possible?

NOTE: I didn't find any API in bluez 5.50 which can provide parsed data.

Thanks,
Mayank

Comment: Was anything wrong with the BlueZ API? It should give you what you want.

Comment: I'm getting bdaddr, rssi and name parameters from bluez api using below param.
1) le_advertising_info //Structure
2) print_advertising_devices() //Function
But, I didn't find any structure/API of bluez which can give parsed sensor data like temperature, accelerometer, humidity.
- Even i didn't find any function of bluez stack which can give 31 bytes of standard buffer packet which is being broadcasted by all beacons.